# effect of parameters on ARMA process

Tags: time-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Effect of moving average parameter on variability and variance of demand](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20039/effect-of-moving-average-parameter-on-variability-and-variance-of-demand)

What is the effect of Theta on MA(1) process, when we move from zero to 1 and from zero to -1, how the process will be affected?
the same question for AR(1)