# Effect of moving average parameter on variability and variance of demand

Tags: time-series

Consider an MA(1) process, $d_{t}=e_{t}-\Theta e_{t-1}$, when $d_t$ is the demand at time $t$ and $e_t$ is error term and $\Theta$ is moving average parameter. Now if $\Theta$ equal to zero so we have a white noise process, if $\Theta$ gets positive values, process is more irregular than white noise, and when the is negative, process is more smoother than white noise. I have two questions:.

1. How can we explain the variability of the process by changing the
   $\Theta$ parameter from zero toward +1 and -1?
2. Why for positive and
   negative $\Theta$, the variance of demand is increasing while we said
   for positive value of Theta the process is irregular than white
   noise and for negative values the process is more smoother than
   white noise.

Comment: What do you mean by process ? Do you mean the values of the forecasts ? The coefficient changes the model errors and the fitted values and the forecasts.

Comment: I mean the moving average process and autoregressive moving average process, when we change these parameters from -1 toward +1, what will happened to these process, fore example when Theta in MA(1) is zero then the process is white noise, now when we move from zero toward -1, whether the moving average process is much more variable than white noise ?

Comment: What you describing is AR(1) process, not MA(1). Could you please clarify? Also how do you measure smoothness? Did you do some simulations, or you calculated some smoothness statistic?

Comment: I'm sorry , Imean dt=et−Θet−1

Comment: I didn't,just I read in this book: time series model by Harvey, page 12.

Comment: which measures I can use to calculate smoothness?

Answer (score 2):

The variance increases as $\Theta$ moves away from zero because the variability of $e_{t-1}$ starts coming into play for the observation at time $t$, increasing the overall variability of $d_t$ around 0.  The process is smoother than white noise, but "smoother" doesn't mean "less variable".  It refers to the visual appearance of the time series plot.  (You can formalize it mathematically, but let's not go there in this heuristic explanation.)   Consider a sine function over $(0, 2\pi)$ - it's pretty smooth, right?  Now consider a plot of 1000 Normal variates with mean 0 and standard deviation 0.1, evenly spaced over $(0, 2\pi)$.  Much rougher, but still a lot less variable.

Comment: Thank you , do you mean there is no relation between variability and smoothness(irregularity)?

Comment: There can be, but doesn't have to be.  Imagine you have a time series $X$; if you multiply all the $x_t$ by 100, it's a lot more variable, but just as smooth.  On the other hand, if you have a smooth time series, and add a random component, e.g., white noise, to it, it gets both rougher and more variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, very interesting,I have another question please. now imagine we have a basic series that follows an MA(1), we apply temporal aggregation on it, as a result variance of aggregated series is greater than basic series and autocorrelation function of aggregated series is smaller than basic series for all Theta values,  when we increase the aggregation level from 2 to m, autocorrelation tends to disappear, how can we analysis this result.

Answer (score 1):

ad 1) sorry I don't get what you mean!

ad 2) According to *Hamilton (1994), page 48* the variance of an MA(1) process is:

$\left(1+\Theta^2\right)\sigma^2$

this explains why the increasing variance, right?

Comment: yes from formula it's clear but how can we explain it conceptually with respect to this explanation: for positive value of Theta the process is irregular than white noise and for negative values the process is more smoother than white noise.

Comment: this is where I can not understand, if for positive Theta value the process is more regular and for negative value process is more smoother than white noise, why variability(variance) is equal for both positive and negative values. for example for Theta=-.5 and Theta=-.5 we will get the same variance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is a question every textbook will deliver. I would suggest [Time Series and its Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387293175). So I will restrict my answer to the basics and a small example in R:

**AR**

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))

ar1<-arima.sim(n = 100, list(ar =.95))
plot(ar1)
acf(ar1)
pacf(ar1)

ar2<-arima.sim(n = 100, list(ar =-.95))
plot(ar2)
acf(ar2)
pacf(ar2)
```

Where the parameters of AR are 0.95 in the first and -0.95 in the second case.

[image]

**MA**

```
plot.new()
par(mfrow=c(2,3))

ma1<-arima.sim(n = 100, list(ma =.95))
plot(ma1)
acf(ma1)
pacf(ma1)

ma2<-arima.sim(n = 100, list(ma =-.95))
plot(ma2) 
acf(ma2)
pacf(ma2)
```

Here we vary the MA parameter with .95 in the first and -.95 in the second case.

[image]

Comment: but ACF for MA(1) is zero when lag>1, isn't it?

Comment: theoretically yes, empirically - this depends